# Is the reduction correct?

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability

Is the following formulation of the reduction correct?

**EDIT:**

Undecidability of an (positive) existential theory $T$ is proved often by reducing an other (positive) existential theory $T'$, which is known to be undecidable,to $T$, i.e., by a mapping from the (positive) existential sentences in the language of $T'$ to the (positive) existential sentences in the language of $T$, $$\phi' \mapsto \phi$$ such that $T'$ proves $\phi'$ iff $T$ proves $\phi$.

$$$$

Is everything correct? Could I improve something at the formulation?

$\phi$ is a formula of $T$, or not?

Comment: Please avoid using the tag decision-theory for computability question; the tag summary shows that the tag is intended for another topic entirely.

Comment: try reading about [Turing completeness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). have never heard of any proof of reduction to undecidability that does not at least implicitly involve it.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "interpretation" - really, a *reduction* of $T$ to $T'$ should just be a function $f$ from the sentences in the language of $T$ to the sentences in the language of $T'$, such that $T$ proves $\varphi$ iff $T'$ proves $f(\varphi)$. This is much broader than a (computable) interpretation.

Regardless of exactly how you define interpretation, your second argument is wrong: saying "$T$ is reducible to $T'$" means that $T$ is *no more complicated than* $T'$. In particular, $T'$ can be extremely complicated and $T$ can be extremely simple. The only way to get a contradiction is to interpret a *complicated* theory inside a *simple* theory.

Comment: I edited my initial post... I changed the formulation of the reduction... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Your second argument is still wrong, for the same reason: if you show $T$ is reducible to $T'$, all that means is that $T'$ is at least as complicated as $T$. If we know $T'$ is *simple*, then this tells us something; but if we know $T'$ is *complicated*, this doesn't tell us anything. (Well, technically it does, but it doesn't address the specific question of whether or not $T$ is decidable.)

Comment: I changed again the edit part... Could you take a look at it? Is it correct now? Could I improve something?

Answer (score 1):

It would be best not to use the technical term reduction.  For what you are working with, the following is a reasonable formulation of the strategy. Let $E$ be the set of existential sentences in some language, and let $T$ be the set of sentences of $E$ that are true in some specified structure $M$.  We are interested in showing that there is no decision procedure to determine membership in $T$.

We usually find a recursive set $E'$ of sentences, and a structure $M'$, with the following properties:

(i) It is known that there is no algorithm for determining whether a sentence of $E'$ is true in $M'$, and

(ii) There is an **algorithm** which, given as input any sentence $\phi'$ of $E'$, produces a sentence $\phi$ of $E$ such that $\phi'$ is true in $M'$ if and only if $\phi$ is true in $M$.

For existential (or positive existential) sentences we can be more specific. Ever since the result of Matijasevich, the set $E'$ used has been,  directly or indirectly, the set of existential sentences in the usual language of arithmetic, and the structure $M'$ has been the natural numbers.